# 3D Manipulator/Origin behaviour issues due to 'Displayer Modifier'

Tags: armature, edit-mode, pose-mode, origin, 3d-manipulator

https://youtu.be/lXeRm33Xi8E

The 3D Manipular/Origin of the individual vertices are not correctly visually displayed.

After the 'Display Modifier' is checked in an Armature Modifier to display the pose of a object in edit mode. The data for the 'origins' of the vertices remain the same, acting as if I am still looking at the 'Rest Position' instead of the 'Pose Position'

Their is some variable I am unaware of that makes it so the data, matches up with the visual aid.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no variable that allows you to do that.  But what you should look into is the Corrective Shapekeys addon, which basically makes a mesh from your pose for editing, then restores the models original pose when you're done editing.  It's bundled with Blender, you just have to enable it.